# My first airflow dag doesn't seem to run (not in the UI)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, airflow, airflow-webserver

**After running my airflow dag :

- The UI only has the admin by default dags even when i refresh
- My dag doesn't appear when i `airflow dags list`

**Pre config**:

- I created a venv with a python3.11.6 version for a folder named extract_load

**The installation steps that i followed** :

1. In my terminal, i first activated my venv in the extract_load folder
2. i run `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` in my terminal
3. then `pip install "apache-airflow[celery]==2.7.3" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.3/constraints-3.11.txt"`
4. then `airflow standalone`
5. Connect to **localhost:8080** after entering my username and password generated with the airflow standalone command

(The doc that i used to install : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html)

**I then ran my airflow script that is located directly in my extract_load file:**

```
#%%
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#%%
today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


default_args = {
    "owner": "example",
    "email": ["example@gmail.com"],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "retries": 2,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=10),
    "start_date": datetime(2023,12,14) 
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'load_test',
    schedule_interval = None,
    default_args = default_args,
)

def test():
    hello = print('Hello')
    return hello

test_run= PythonOperator(
    task_id='hello_test',
    python_callable=test,
    dag=dag,
)

test_run
```

Then i run the script, the script is working well (VScode doesn't return any mistake) but nothing happens

Comment: How did you run the script ? Using only python ? The DAG execution is to be handled by Airflow's scheduler. Have your tried `airflow tasks` and `airflow dags backfill` mentionned in the link you provided ?

Comment: @vdolez indeed, by trying to run the tasks with the command : 
airflow tasks test load_test hello_test 2015-01-01
i can now see the dag in my airflow UI. But Oddly, when i try to click on the dag in the UI, it doesn't open and this error appears above : "DAG "load_test" seems to be missing from DagBag."

also, when i run "airflow dags list" in my terminal, the dag load_test does not appear

Comment: Have you tried using a date occuring after the `start_date` you provided ? Also, is your DAG in the AIRFLOW_HOME folder ? Is the DAG visible in the UI ?

Comment: I can see my file in airflow / scheduler, the dag is visible in the UI, but when i click on it this message appear : "DAG "load_test" seems to be missing from DagBag." 
Is it possible that i need to change the path of the dags_folder variable ?
i have : dags_folder = /Users/hirchamghermani/airflow/dags in the airflow.cfg file
should i change it to this instead ? -> dags_folder = path/to/my/project/dags

Comment: You might try removing the line `"owner": "example",` to inherits from the default owner. It might be security related.